# Is there any plastic wrapping service in Copenhagen airport?

Tags: luggage, airports, denmark, copenhagen, cph

Do you know if there's any plastic wrap service in Copenhagen airport ?

Answer (score 5):

I travel from or through Copenhagen frequently, and have never noticed this service. In fact, I have never seen it in any Scandinavian airport, so I would go on a limb and say no.